# Maven and Svn Plugin is not working in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: maven, svn, maven-plugin, eclipse-indigo

I am using Eclipse Helios and want to migrate to Indigo.
I have installed Indigo and m2e and subclipse plugin. I was able to import maven project as well as projects from svn.

But from the next day, Svn is missing from perspective and while trying to import maven projects, I am not able to find maven in the list.

I have uninstalled and installed again but same issue occured again.

Is it because both Helios and Indigo installed in my machine ?

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it because both Helios and Indigo installed in my machine ?
```

That shouldnt create any issue at all. I have multiple versions of eclipse installed in my system and they all seem to work fine.

As far as the m2e and subclipse plugin is concenred, I have used it personally on Indigo without any issue at all and there doesn't seem to be any incompatibility issue.

It maybe possible that eclipse plugins have gotten a bit messy and need a re-start. Goto the directory where you have installed eclipse and add this line on the top of the eclipse.ini file.

```
-clean
-startup
....the rest of the settings and params
```

Then start your eclipse, it will attempt to clean and re-load each plugin again.